# Seeking design advice or suggestions for my table

Tags: tikz-styles, threeparttable

I have the following table:

[image]

Does anyone with a flair for design have a good idea how I can make it less ugly? Ideally, I want that the readers immediately sees that the table consists of two parts ("long-run" and "short-run") and that each part has its own numbers. I tried to use a line between the two sections, but it didn't really look "professional"...

Would be grateful for any advice or suggestions - thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace,amsmath,graphicx,float}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} 
\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, calc, positioning, quotes, shapes, patterns}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=18pt}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nccmath}  
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption[Comparison of critical diversion ratios and switching levels (A)]
{Comparison of critical diversion ratios and switching levels (A).}
\label{Comparison1}
\centering 
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}} c c c c}
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{5\% Critical Price Increase} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{10\% Critical Price Increase} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
                             & \vtop{\hbox{\strut One-sided}\hbox{\strut calculation}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut Two-sided}\hbox{\strut calculation}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut One-sided}\hbox{\strut calculation}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut Two-sided}\hbox{\strut calculation}} \\
\midrule
Long-run:                        &             &           &             &    \\ 
Critical diversion ratios        & 8.7\%       & 5.4\%     & 16\%        & 13.5\%     \\[1ex]
Critical switching levels        & 16.5\%      & 11.1\%    & 30.4\%      & 27.5\%     \\[1ex]

Short-run:                       &             &           &             &    \\ 
Critical diversion ratios        & 8.7\%       & 5.4\%     & 16\%        & 13.5\%     \\[1ex]
Critical switching levels        & 16.5\%      & 11.1\%    & 30.4\%      & 27.5\%     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Only thing I'd definitely do is align the decimal points in the columns (using dcolumn or siunitx packages) then if you want to stress the gap increase the gap before short-run (a bit) or make short-run and long-run bold.

Comment: I'd rotate "Long run" and "Short run" by 90 degrees and put them as headers that cover the two corresponding rows in a new first column. After that, check whether a \midrule or extra space between these two groups looks better.

Comment: Please could you make your example a bit more minimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far you table is not so ugly ... but I would redesign your table to:

[image]

However, answer can be only opinion-based: different people, different taste :)

From preamble of your MWE I preserve only to table related packages and add `siunitx` (see *David Carlisle* comment):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage[margin=1cm, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow, tabularx, threeparttable}% <-- collected here
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering#1}}% <-- added
\usepackage{siunitx}% <-- added

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption[Comparison of critical diversion ratios and switching levels (A)]
        {Comparison of critical diversion ratios and switching levels (A).}
\label{Comparison1}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l
                        *{4}{S[table-format=2.1,
                               table-space-text-post=\si{\%},
                               table-align-text-post=false]<{\,\%}}
                            }
\toprule
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\SI{5}{\%} Critical Price Increase} 
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\SI{10}{\%} Critical Price Increase} \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{Calculations:}
                            & \mcx{One-sided}   & \mcx{Two-sided}   & \mcx{One-sided}   & \mcx{Two-sided}   \\
    \midrule
\emph{Long-run:}            & \multicolumn{4}{c}{}                                                          \\
Critical diversion ratios   & 8.7               & 5.4               & 16                & 13.5              \cr
Critical switching levels   & 16.5              & 11.1              & 30.4              & 27.5              \cr
    \addlinespace
\emph{Short-run:}           & \multicolumn{4}{c}{}                                                          \\
Critical diversion ratios   & 8.7               & 5.4               & 16                & 13.5              \cr
Critical switching levels   & 16.5              & 11.1              & 30.4              & 27.5              \cr

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Note:**

- for aligning of numbers is used `S` column type from `siunitx` where

  - with options `table-format` (it is reserved two character spaces for integers and one for decimals
  - with option `table-space-text-post=\si{\%}` is reserved space for `%` which folows numbers in columns
  - with option `table-align-text-post=false` is ordered that percent sign follows imidiatel to last digit in number (and not to reserved space for numbers)
  - with `<{\,\%}` is to each cell added `%. Consequently, the cell, where it shouldn't appear had to be`\multicolumn{...}{..}}
- the command `\mcx{...}` is defined because of two reasons:

  - for shorter table's code (less important)
  - for reserving equal width for all columns with number. With this the sum of two column widths is bigger than natural width of `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\SI{10}{\%} Critical Price Increase}` and consequently the columns under this header preserve equal width.
- added package `siunitx` is very useful and complex, not only for design beautiful table, but in the first place for correct writing of units, formation of numbers, uncertainty of numbers etc. It is worth to read its documentation and see how it can improve your writing.

Comment: Thank you very much - also to David Carlisle. I will definitely use this suggestion also for my other tables.

Comment: @Malganas, please don't rush with accepting answer, probably will appear more answer which you will  liked more :).  Meanwhile I slightly change code in MWE (with goal to make it more concise).

Comment: Right, thank you for the tip :-) I like yours though! I'm now trying to to understand what you did to also use it.

Comment: Great "Note". This will be part of my code snippet collection.