# How to insert a gap between column titles?

Tags: tables

I am trying to produce a latex table from Stata, and I want to group my regressions and add titles. So I used Stata code "esttab, mygroup()". However the table created by this code looks like this:
[image: there is no gap between the two groups]

and i want it to look like this:
[image]

I knew this could be done manually in Latex by inserting an empty column. But is there a more convenient way?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you show? If your code uses `\cmidrule` from booktabs, you might want to use `\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}` in order to get the small gap in the horizontal line.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you looking for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
    \toprule
    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Weight}             
                            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Length} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-3}   \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    & (1)       & (2)       & (3)       & (4)       \\
    & {price}   & {price}   & {price}   & {price}   \\
    \midrule
weight  &       &           &           &           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

However, your table have other issues too (aligning numbers in table, etc). For this you should look `siunitx` and `threeparttable` package if it can help you in table design.

As an example of similar table design see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366134/seeking-design-advice-or-suggestions-for-my-table/366142#366142).

Answer (score 0):

You can add empty space by inserting `@{\hskip amountOfSpace}` between the specifiers, see minimal example 1. You can also add other things between the columns insted of the standard space, try e.g. example 2

First example:

```
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hskip 1cm}c@{\hskip 2cm}c}
    Djamble&Ha& Blar\\
    Foo& Bar& Barfoo
\end{tabular}
```

Second example:

```
\begin{tabular}{l@{ or }c@{\hskip 2cm}c}
    Djamble&Ha& Blar\\
    Foo& Bar& Barfoo
\end{tabular}
```

---

[image: Screenshot of output on my machine]

Comment: In their question, the OP showed an image of the desired output that has a small gap in the horizontal line. Could you please add an explanation on how one can achieve such a gap with the approch in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! The code for table titles shown in the image is:

```
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Weight}                 &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Length}                 \\\cline{2-3}\cline{4-5}
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{price}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{price}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{price}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{price}\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
```

and this is created automatically by Stata code:

eststo clear
sysuse auto

eststo: qui reg price weight
eststo: qui reg price weight foreign

eststo: qui reg price length
eststo: qui reg price length foreign

esttab using example.tex, replace mgroups( "Weight" "Length"  , pattern(1 0 1 0 ) span prefix(\multicolumn{@span}{c}{) suffix(}) erepeat(\cline{@span}))

Comment: Do you have two accounts? Is this part of question above?

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Yes, this is part of the question. I will merge the two accounts together. Thank you!